# Is there a recommended strategy for keeping a single timestamp for multiple models in multiple tables?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Let's say there are 3 tables like below:

```
[chatroom]
- id
- title
- updated_at

[chat]
- id
- chatroom_id
- message
- updated_at

[actor]
- id
- chatroom_id
- name
- updated_at
```

Each table has an `updated_at` timestamp which is updated whenever its data is changed.
What I want is to update the chatroom's timestamp when there's a new chat or a new actor. There are solutions using SQL trigger but that's out of the option for me since our DBA is against it. Is there a different strategy to achieve this other than programmatically updating it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update table "b" when table "a" is updated, you don't have that many choices.  Some are:

- Use a trigger.
- Write a stored procedure that does all the updates you want -- and be sure this is used for all updates.
- Do something similar to a stored procedure on the application side.

The trigger is the most natural way to do this in SQL.  However, I'm not so sure it is necessary  Why not just *query* the results when you want it?  Something like this:

```
select greatest(cr.updated_at,
                (select max(c.updated_at) from chat c where c.chatroom_id = cr.id),
                (select max(a.updated_at) from actor a where a.chatroom_id = cr.id)
               )
from chatroom c;
```

With the right indexes, you might find that such an approach works fine for what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I guess updating it real time isn't worth digging for. Thanks for the new direction about querying instead!